# C++ Pointer Object Functor

Tags: c++, operators, functor

I'm confused about why C++ does not allow you to use a functor on a pointer. For instance, if I have something like this as my class:

```
class Character{


    public:
        Character();
        ~Character();
        void operator()() {cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl;}//this is the functor operator

};
```

When I do something like this, I get an error that says I can't call character as a function...

```
Character * character = new Character();

    character();

    delete character;
```

But this works fine:

```
Character character;
character();
```

How would I go about accessing this operator in the first scenario? Is it even possible?

Comment: `character->operator()()` or `(*character)()`, pointers are not the object they're pointing to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, dereference the pointer:

```
(*character)();
```

Or more verbosely:

```
character->operator()();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform indirection via the pointer to use the pointed-to object:

```
(*character)()
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a pointer,  that's why:

<strike>`character->();` or</strike> `(*character)()` are your friends.